# How to remove the blank space in bottom after Container translated to top in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, padding

After applying `transform` property to a container, it gives an extra padding in the bottom

```
Container(
  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, -70, 0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    border: Border.all(
      color: ZeplinColors.light_blue_grey,
      width: 3.0,
    ),
  ),
  child: const CircleAvatar(
    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
      'https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-bootstrap-laravel-admin-template/demo-1/images/portrait/small/avatar-s-7.jpg',
    ),
    radius: 55.0,
  ),
),
```

Example (Inspected with Dart DevTools):

[image: Example]

How to avoid this extra padding ?

Here is the [DartPad link](https://dartpad.dev/?id=2d585c8fefcf1503d9a28d0b1b9e1ba2&null_safety=true) of what I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The catch was to NOT use `transform` and because no matter where you transform your container, it is going to take the space it requires originally. The container only use the space required by it.

[image: Solution]

So I used a `Stack` for this image with `padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: circleRadius / 2)` for other widgets. Got the idea from this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51353128/15320000). Thanks to it.

I also made a [DartPad Solution link](https://dartpad.dev/?id=8b1614e018c7f26295801b5750df2b16&null_safety=true)